# Как в маршруте сделать название папки равному ID в Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vue-router

Нужно:

- создать такой маршрут: "1234"; "1234/catalog"; "1234/reviews" (где 1234 это динамичный ID)
- при заходе на страницу взять этот ID для дальнейшего использования

Нужно использовать:

- Nuxt
- Дефолтный модуль маршрутизатора Vue Router

Есть у кого-то варианты реализации?

Comment: Варианты со сторонними дополнительными библиотеками или модулями так же приветствуються

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во `Vue-router` вы можете использовать динамический корневой маршрут. Для этого нужно создать роутер примерно со следующей конфигурацией:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: "/:id/",
    component: test,
    name: 'id',
    props: (route) => ({
      id: route.params.id,
      query: route.query,
    }),
    children: [{
      path: "catalog",
      name: 'nested',
      component: nested,
      props: (route) => ({
        id: route.params.id,
        query: route.query,
      }),
    }, ]
  }, ],
});
```

Создав компоненты и расставив их на нужные места вы можете получить то, что вам, вероятно, нужно. Привожу пример для реализации во `Vue`:

```js
const test = Vue.component("test", {
  props: ["id"],
  template: `
  <div>
    <p>Нажмите ссылку для перехода к каталогу</p>
    <hr>
    <router-link exact :to="{name: 'catalog', params: { id} }">catalog для {{ id }}</router-link>
    <router-link exact :to="{name: 'reviews', params: { id} }">reviews для {{ id }}</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <hr>
  </div>`,
});

const nested = Vue.component("nested", {
  props: ["id"],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>{{ $route.name }} для {{ id }}</h1>
    <p>Входные параметры (props)</p>
    <pre>{{ $props }}</pre>
  </div>`,
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: "/:id/",
    component: test,
    name: 'id',
    props: (route) => ({
      id: route.params.id,
      query: route.query,
    }),
    children: [{
        path: "catalog",
        name: 'catalog',
        component: nested,
        props: (route) => ({
          id: route.params.id,
          query: route.query,
        }),
      },
      {
        path: "reviews",
        name: 'reviews',
        component: nested,
        props: (route) => ({
          id: route.params.id,
          query: route.query,
        }),
      },
    ]
  }, ],
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  watch: {
    "$route.fullPath": {
      handler: function(path) {
        this.setNewPath(path);
      },
    },
  },
  data: {
    links: [{
        id: 1234,
        title: "Страница 1234",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Страница 2",
      },
    ],
  },
  created() {
    this.setNewPath();
  },
  methods: {
    goPath() {
      this.$router.push(this.path);
    },
    setNewPath(path) {
      this.path = path || this.$route.fullPath;
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.8.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Путь <input id="input" v-if="path" type="text" name="path" v-model="path" style="width: 100%; padding: 10px" @keyup.enter="goPath" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="link in links">
      <router-link exact :to="{name: 'id', params: { id: link.id} }">{{ link.title}}</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

и, учитывая, то, что `nuxt` использует `Vue-router` для создания маршрутизации, тоже  самое можно реализовать и в нем. По умолчанию достаточно создать файл `_id.vue`и директорию `_id` в директории `pages`(не забываем в директории `_id` создать нужные вложенные маршруты(допустим `catalog`, `reviews`, `index` - по умолчанию)). Эти условия уже создадут роуты, вам останется только вставить ссылки на нужные места.

Очень важно: для работы вложенных роутов в `nuxt` - не забудьте вставить `nuxt-child` в компонент. Более подробно обо всем этом можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing) и привожу примерную реализацию вышеизложенного в `nuxt` - https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-test-router-begin-yfv7f.

Comment: Да, это сработало, спасибо большое

Comment: Но, есть вопрос, там разметка страниц довольно странная. Как работает индекс файл который находится в папке в сравнении с файлом _id.vue который находится вне этой папки?

Comment: `_id.vue` сам отображается в компоненте `Nuxt` и содержит компонент `NuxtChild`, так вот в `NuxtChild`  отображается `_id/index.vue` при пути`/:id/` и соответственно `_id/catalog.vue` при пути `/:id/catalog` и так далее, т.е. `_id/index.vue` отображается по умолчанию, если дочерний роут не инициирован( т.е. просто `/:id/` или `/:id`)